# How to 'center align' image and text in cell of grid view

Tags: css, drupal-7, view

In my site I am using the grid format of Views to display the Image, surname and first name of users on my site. The grid view has 4 columns.

I noticed that the image and text in each cell is aligned to the left.

Please how can i center align the image and text in each cell.

Below are the first lines of HTML:

```
`<div class="view view-user-pictures view-id-user_pictures view-display-id-block view-dom-id-1120"> <div class="view-content"> <table class="views-view-grid cols-4"> <tbody>`
```

I have tried adding `table.views-view-grid td {
   text-align: center;
}` to the style.css file. bt it does not work.

Thank you.

Comment: Please submit an example on jsfiddle.net and post the link here.

Comment: i don't understand how to go about submitting an example on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

That css should work, and it does in this example of what you provided: [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Sk4BS/3/) using
    `table.views-view-grid td {text-align: center;}`
I would suggest using your browser inspector to see if the style you are adding isn't being overwritten by another rule elsewhere. Besides that you'll need to provide a better example of the code than what you have there. Do you have a link to the example site you can provide?